# Timing a promise call correctly in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

In a service module, I am making a $http call to read a config file and then based on it, making another $http call to get some values.  My problem is that the second call fails if run straight through, but when I debug it it succeeds.  So, it seems to me, that the chained promise is not structured correctly.

```
angular.module('swwf-app').service('lwwfService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, $rootScope)
    {
        var lwwfService = this,
            configDefer = $http.get('/config.json').then(setupConfig).catch(configError),
            locationDefer = configDefer.then(setupLocation).catch(configError);

    function setupLocation(config)
    {
        if($rootScope.shortname)
        {
            return $http({
                url: config.backend_endpoint + '/locations/' + $rootScope.shortname,
                method: "GET"
            }).then(function(loc){
                return loc.data;
            });
        }
```

When I call this, my `locationDefer` is failing.  How can I structure this, so that the locationDefer succeeds?

These above functions are called by another service function as below

```
    lwwfService.getReports = function(params)
    {
        params = params || {};

        return $q.all([configDefer, locationDefer]).then(function(responses)
        {
            var config = responses[0];
            // Line 55: this following line generates the error
            var location = responses[1][0];
            var thisUrl = config.backend_endpoint + '/location/'+location.location_id+'/reports';
            return $http(
            {
                url: thisUrl,
                method: "GET",
                params: params || {}
            });
        });
    };

    function configError(err)
        {
            throw 'Error encountered:' + err;
        };
```

The error I am getting in browser console upon calling is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at lwwfService.js:55
...
```

Line 55 is shown in the code above as a comment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question, at the bottom you say "Line 55 is", but you didn't actually include that bit.

Comment: If `locationDefer` is failing, your `configError` handler must (re)throw. Please show us its code. Also, does the error handler return the `undefined` that you didn't expect?

Comment: `[configDefer, locationDefer]` are supposed to be undefined in your `getReports` function. They're local to `lwwfService` factory.

Comment: I've added the configError function in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi  `[configDefer, locationDefer]` are visible.  This code runs as expected when running through Chrome Devtools debugger.

Comment: either `$rootScope.shortname` is "falsey", which would result in `setupLocation` resulting in undefined - or `loc.data` is undefined

Comment: @Jaromanda. I've verified through dev tools that `$rootScope.shortname` is present.  So the 2nd answer must be true.  Also the `loc.data` gets populated correctly, if I slow down the chain by putting breakpoints in the debugger. I put breakpoint on line 55 and that made it work correctly.

Comment: @Piyush: If it's a heisenbug, try using `console.log` instead of breakpoints

Comment: It seems that in the factory function, I can access $rootScope, but not one of its properties.  When I `console.log($rootScope)` it has the property `shortname` with the correct value, but when I `console.log($rootScope.shortname)` it comes as undefined.  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Try `console.log($rootScope['shortname'])`.

Comment: The problem was with populating $rootScope.shortname.  Once I fixed that, this logic started working as expected.  Thanks, all.